# V1/customers/me rest endpoint returning same response for each request

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I am working on **magento2.2.6**, Rest api endpoing **V1/customers/me** returning a single response for each token.

I have generated tokens for different users, but it always return the same response, even any wrong token is also passed then the result is same, it seems like it has cached the response.

I run the following commands to reconfigure and clear cache:

- **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**
- ** rm -rf var/cache/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf var/page_cache/* && rm -rf var/composer_home/* && rm -rf pub/static/* && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean **

But no gains.

There are 2 stores in this magento setup and it has stuck with two customers data on each request for any customer token, either it is correct or wrong.

Please guide me, How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain in detail about that token which you have using for access this api, are you using different customers token, right?rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Comment: I generate the token by rest/V1/integration/customer/token api with email and password input. On different customer token, it returns only a single user data in response.

Comment: Have you tried reindex? php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: GET https://demo.site.com/rest/V1/customers/me

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer s4f6s6df65sdf6a4sf656df5

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala, no benefit of indexer:reindex, It seems api enpoint has been cached; there is no effect of bearer token on its result. I cleared/flushed all caches but no gain.

Comment: it looks like some conflict issue. find the preference or duplicate api for rest/V1/customers/me in your app/ directory

Comment: Still no idea, what is going on.., I setup the same application on my local machine and it works fine on localhost.

Comment: @NaveenPal Disable your all the custom module and check.

Comment: Thanks you very much for sharing your precious time, there was varnish cache on server level which was caching all get request. Application is working fine.